# simple_form `selected` to set dropdown default value does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu, simple-form

In my Rails 3(!) project I’m using the simple_form gem to handle all my forms. In one of them I need a drop-down list to have a pre-set value. I tried two different approaches:

```
= form.input :country_id, :input_html => {"value" => preset_country}, :label => false
```

AND

```
= form.input :country_id, :label => false, selected => preset_country
```

In both examples, the generated HTML code is valid – among other options I get:

```html
<option value="21" selected="selected">Argentina</option>
```

But it does not seem to have any impact on what is displayed on the screen – all I see is “Please select country” instead of “Argentina”. Any idea on what can be wrong here? I have been using simple form for some time and never encountered such behavior…

The full generated HTML of the `<select>`:

```html
<select class="select optional disabled" disabled="disabled" id="subscription_channel_country_id"><option value="">Please select country</option>
                <option value="0">United States</option>
                <option value="21" selected="selected">Argentina</option>
                <option value="2">Australia</option>
                <option value="12">Austria</option>
                <option value="10">Belgium</option>
                <option value="8">Brazil</option>
                <option value="9">Canada</option>
                <option value="28">Czech Republic</option>
                <option value="17">Denmark</option>
                <option value="14">Finland</option>
                <option value="5">France</option>
                <option value="3">Germany</option>
                <option value="24">Greece</option>
                <option value="27">Hungary</option>
                <option value="11">India</option>
                <option value="29">Ireland</option>
                <option value="6">Italy</option>
                <option value="18">Mexico</option>
                <option value="1">Netherlands</option>
                <option value="22">New Zealand</option>
                <option value="15">Norway</option>
                <option value="16">Poland</option>
                <option value="25">Portugal</option>
                <option value="13">Russia</option>
                <option value="26">Slovakia</option>
                <option value="4">Spain</option>
                <option value="19">Sweden</option>
                <option value="23">Switzerland</option>
                <option value="20">Turkey</option>
                <option value="7">United Kingdom</option>
                <option value="0">United States</option></select>
```

Comment: Can you post the lines of HTML with the “Please select country” `<option>` and the beginning and ending tag of the surrounding `<select>`? The attributes of those elements might be relevant. And what is the relative order of the “Argentina” and “Please select country” options in the HTML?

Comment: i pasted html into my question

Comment: That code actually works in my browser. Do you have any javascript doing something special?

Comment: need to check, that actually might be good trace because the system is not mine

Comment: yes, you are correct, i removed all the js and it started to work, just need to debug it carefully now, thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers save the form status between "soft" reloads (for instance Firefox).

If the selected option is given, it should work properly. Are you simply reloading the page?

Try to "hard reload" (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> in some browsers) or just click on the address bar and press enter.